# Android mediaPlayer Seekbar progress on other item of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

i build an app like image bellow an i want to when click on player boutton only medi witch attached to seekbar start to play like whatsapp messenger. it's work perfectly but when my listView scrolled seekBar progress on other list item. i don't know why ! i try everything since 5 days but everything i try don't work. please can you help me ? thank all for your help.

i will posted my source code if necessary.

[image]

My custom view code is bellow:

```
    public class VoiceItemView extends MessageBaseItemView<VoiceItemModel>
        {

    View view;
    private SeekBar audioSeekbar;
    private ImageButton audioControls;
    private TextView link;
    private VoiceRecord mVoiceRecord;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    private TalkActivity talkActivity = new TalkActivity();
    private Handler mHandler;
    private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
        new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                switch (focusChange) {
                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                    mPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                break;

                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                    mPlayer.pause();
                break;

                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                    mPlayer.pause();
                break;

                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :

                    mPlayer.start();
                break;
                default: break;
            }
         }
    };

    public VoiceItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public VoiceItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VoiceItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(VoiceItemModel item){
        super.bind(item);
        audioControls.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_icon);
        link.setText(item.getFilePath());

    }

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
    public void init(){
        super.init();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.talk_voice, null);

        link = new TextView(getContext());
        link.setVisibility(GONE);

        audioSeekbar = new SeekBar(getContext());
        audioControls = new ImageButton(getContext());  

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(370, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        audioSeekbar.setProgressDrawable(CustomSeekBar.setProgress(12, 8, getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_soft), Color.WHITE)); 
        audioSeekbar.setThumb(CustomSeekBar.setThumb(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_soft), 40));
        audioSeekbar.setLayoutParams(params);
        mVoiceRecord = new VoiceRecord();
        mVoiceRecord.setContext(getContext());


        audioControls.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                final int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                if(mPlayer == null){

                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {

                        mPlayer.setDataSource(link.getText().toString());
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                        mPlayer.start();
                        mPlayer.seekTo(audioSeekbar.getProgress());
                    }
                    final int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
                    audioSeekbar.setMax(duration);

                    final int amoungToupdate = duration/100;

                    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            talkActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    if(mPlayer != null){
                                        int mCurrentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                                        audioSeekbar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                                    }
                                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };

                    new Timer().schedule(task, amoungToupdate);

                }
            }
        });


        setViewToContainer(audioSeekbar);
        setViewToContainer(audioControls);
    }

}
```

and bellow source is by parent class MessageBaseItemView

```
abstract public class MessageBaseItemView<T> extends LinearLayout implements ICustomModel<T>{

    private TextView timeStamp;
    private ImageView avatar;
    private RelativeLayout container;
    private View viewRight, viewLeft;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    public MessageBaseItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MessageBaseItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MessageBaseItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }


    public void setViewToContainer(List<View> listView){
        for (View view : listView) {
            container.addView(view);
        }
    }

    public void setViewToContainer(View view){
        container.addView(view);
    }

    public RelativeLayout getContainer(){
        return this.container;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(){

        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_talk_list_bubble_left, this);

        viewRight = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_talk_list_bubble_right, null);
        viewLeft = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_talk_list_bubble_left, null);

        timeStamp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
        avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    }
}
```

i use my VoiceItemView in a adapter and i use this adapter in listFragment like bellow

```
public class ProfileFragment extends ListFragment {

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundleSavedInstance){

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_profile, viewGroup, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

DynamicMessageAdapter adapter = new DynamicMessageAdapter(getActivity());


        List<VoiceItemModel> listVoice = new ArrayList<VoiceItemModel>();

        listVoice.add(new VoiceItemModel(2, "18:00", "/storage/emulated/0/Flirt/Media/Talk/Voices Mates/2015-05-27/case.aac"));
        listVoice.add(new VoiceItemModel(2, "12:09 PM", "/storage/emulated/0/Flirt/Media/Talk/Voices Mates/2015-05-27/destin.aac"));
        listVoice.add(new VoiceItemModel(4, "18:00", "/storage/emulated/0/Flirt/Media/Talk/Voices Mates/2015-05-27/boo.aac"));


        adapter.bindVoice(listVoice);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @Mantas i edited my post for add my source code, thank for your help